# Show that each of these conditional statements is a tautology. Please show each step and the laws you use.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is what I have so far, any suggestion??

a)  ¬p→(p→q)
≡¬ p∨(¬p∨q)
≡¬ p∨¬(¬p∨q)
≡¬ p∨(p∧¬q)
≡(¬p∨p)∧(¬p∨¬q)

Answer (score 0):

You went astray in your first step: $\varphi\to\psi$ is equivalent to $\neg\varphi\lor\psi$, so you should have

$$\neg p\to(p\to q)\equiv\neg\neg p\lor(\neg p\lor q)\;,$$

not $\neg p\lor(\neg p\lor q)$. Now you can continue

$$\neg\neg p\lor(\neg p\lor q)\equiv p\lor(\neg p\lor q)\equiv(p\lor\neg p)\lor q\;;$$

can you finish it from there?

By the way, note that $\neg p\lor(\neg p\lor q)\equiv(\neg p\lor\neg p)\lor q\equiv\neg p\lor q$, which clearly is *not* a tautology; had you made this immediate simplification, you might have caught the error right away.

Also, it’s not true that $\neg p\lor(\neg p\lor q)\equiv\neg p\lor\neg(\neg p\lor q)$: the lefthand side, as we just saw, is equivalent to $\neg p\lor q$, while the righthand side is, as you correctly said, equivalent to $(\neg p\lor p)\land(\neg p\lor\neg q)$, which in turn simplifies to $\neg p\lor\neg q$ (why?). If $p$ and $q$ are both true, $\neg p\lor q$ is true, but $\neg p\lor\neg q$ is false, so the two cannot be equivalent.